# Haskell quickcheck issue

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I am writing a simple test using quickcheck.

```
import Test.QuickCheck

f :: Int -> Int 
f x
        | x < 0 = (-x)
        | otherwise = x 

main = do
        putStrLn "Testing"
        quickCheck ((\x -> ((f x) >= 0)) :: Int -> Bool)
```

Whenever I run this via `$ runhaskell test.hs`, I see one of 2 different results.
Either I get:
Testing
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
Or:
I get no output, and the program terminates.
I cannot reason about this behavior.

This is on Quickcheck 2.5.1.1, and ghc 7.4.2.

Comment: You don't need the <pre> tags; [Markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) doesn't recognize those language declarations anyway.  Just indent your code four spaces, using the `{}` button above the code editor window.

Comment: ah, thanks! Havent used StackOverflow in a while.

Comment: Can't reproduce with ghc 7.4.1 and quickcheck 2.5

Comment: Do you change the property so that quickcheck should fail, and then you get no output (eg change `>=` to `<`), or is it the same code that randomly switches between passing the tests, and giving no output?

Comment: Does it also switch between printing and not printing a) in GHCi, b) when you run compiled code?

Comment: @Boris, yes I tried that. I still get the switching between printing and not printing.

Comment: @DanielFischer yes it works fine in GHCi and compiled code. (btw GHCi segfaulted once at start time, that is before loading the prompt)

Comment: Then it would seem that `runhaskell` is somehow causing it. But GHCi segfaulting seems odd. Any information on why?

Comment: It might be worth trying to run `runhaskell test.hs; echo $?`. This will give you the exit code of runhaskell. If it is non-zero, this indicates an error; if it is greater than 127, it indicates that runhaskell was killed by a signal.